# Webpack + React + Typescript

Tags: typescript, reactjs, webpack

Is it possible to use webpack with React and Typescript and be able to bundle those into a web bundle, but still be able to debug original TypeScript and React code? In webpack I'm using ts-loader and ts-jsx-loader plus devtool: "source-map", but when I try to do browser debugging, I can't see original ts code but instead I see code which has been changed by webpack.

My current basic webpack.config.js file:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
  entry: ['./app/main.ts'],
  output: {
    path: './build',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  debug: true,
  devtool: 'source-map',
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader!ts-jsx-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "version": "1.5.0-alpha",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noLib": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true
    },
    "files": [
        "./AppComponent.ts",
        "./libs/jsx.d.ts",
        "./libs/react.d.ts",
        "./libs/webpack-runtime.d.ts",
        "./main.ts"
    ]
}
```

For example - my oryginal .ts file looks like:

```
import React = require('react');

class AppComponent extends React.Component<any, any> {
  render () {
    return React.jsx(`
      <h1>He world!</h1>
    `);
  }
};
export = AppComponent;
```

and in chrome debugger it looks like this:

```
var __extends = this.__extends || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    __.prototype = b.prototype;
    d.prototype = new __();
};
var React = __webpack_require__(2);
var AppComponent = (function (_super) {
    __extends(AppComponent, _super);
    function AppComponent() {
        _super.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    AppComponent.prototype.render = function () {
        return (React.createElement("h1", null, "He world!"));
    };
    return AppComponent;
})(React.Component);
;
module.exports = AppComponent;


/*****************
 ** WEBPACK FOOTER
 ** ./app/AppComponent.ts
 ** module id = 158
 ** module chunks = 0
 **/
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use the ts-jsx-loader.

In your tsconfig.json file you just need something like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    "sourceMap": true,
    // ... other options
  }
}
```

And of course, you still need the devtool option in the webpack config file

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that you have not specified `sourceMap` in your [tsconfig.json](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json) file, so the TypeScript compiler is not outputting sourcemaps.

Comment: I've added sourceMap to tsconfig.json but still doesn't work

Comment: So I just tried this out using your configuration. The only thing I noted was that, assuming you're using Chrome, you need to keep the devtools open while you load the page, otherwise the sourcemap isn't loaded. Also note that both the original Javascript and the TypeScript are both shown under sources, not just the TypeScript. Lastly, to ensure everything is OK, you should check your bundle.js to make sure it has a sourceMappingURL and that the bundle.js.map file looks OK (you should see some TypeScript in it)

Comment: Thank you for your help but unfortunately it still doesn't work. I've posted some example showing original code and code from debugger.

Comment: In your output, do you have a file called bundle.js.map? (should sit next to bundle.js)

Comment: @JamesBrantly I'm running into a similar situation as the original SO owner and I do see a bundle.js.map file. However, I'm still unable to see the source maps in Chrome. Any thoughts on what else this could be?